# Permute any two entries in a $n\times n$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an $8 \times 8$ matrix with integer coefficients. I want to permute two entries in $A$, any two entries as needed: In general, for any two entries $a_j,b_k$ in the matrix is it possible to do this with some matrix $B$ dependent on $a_j,b_k$?

I know about permutation matrices, but they only permute entire rows and columns not individual entries.

**Edit 1:**

For example: Say I want to permute $x_{12}$ with $x_{33}$, I want a matrix $B$ suh that :

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & \dots  & x_{3n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{n1} & x_{n2} & x_{n3} & \dots  & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{33} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{12} & \dots  & x_{3n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{n1} & x_{n2} & x_{n3} & \dots  & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks.

P.s[Moderators]: Edit tags as appropriate, I added as many as made sense to me.

Comment: What do you mean by permuting two entries? What do you mean is it possible to do this with some matrix $B$?

Comment: I will edit. One sec.

Comment: Here $A$ is said to be an $8\times 8$ integer matrix.  The totality of such matrices spans a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $64$, and there is a linear transformation that swaps the $i,j$-entry with (say) the $k,m$-entry.  However this is a linear transformation on the $64$-dimensional space, so it is not represented by any matrix $B$ that is $8\times 8$ like the matrices $A$.

Comment: The dimension of B is not a restriction...it could be as big as it needs to be, so long as I know how to create them.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, set $B = A^{-1}C$ where $C$ is the desired output matrix.

Comment: In general, $A$ is "almost always" non-invertible.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost always" in this case?  That statement is false for most meanings of the term.

Comment: In any case I understood the problem to require $B$ that depends on the positions $ij$ and $km$ to swap, but not on the entries of $A$ otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The dimension of $B$ is not a restriction...it could be as big as it needs to be, so long as I know how to create them.

Consider a "flatten" operator $\iota$ that maps $A$ to a single row of length $n^2$ by concatenating successive rows of $A$.  Then let $B$ be the $n^2\times n^2$ permutation matrix that swaps entries $(i-1)n+j$ and $(k-1)n+m$ for any fixed $i,j,k,m \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Then $\iota(A)B = \iota(\tilde{A})$ where $\tilde{A}$ is the result of swapping the $i,j$ and $k,m$ entries of $A$.

So if you allow for "flattening" of $A$ and unflattening the result of multiplying the long row by $B$ to $\tilde{A}$, then we can swap two specific entries of matrix $A$ through multiplication by (much larger) matrix $B$.  Some programming languages (such as Matlab/Octave/MLab) support this through a "reshape" function.

Comment: This is useful.Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt you can do it with "a matrix" $B$.

Here's an ugly algorithm using matrix arithmetic. You can multiply on the left and on the right by matrices with one $1$ and all the rest $0$ to build a matrix with one entry untouched and all the other entries $0$. Do this for all $64$ entries in the original matrix, permute rows and columns for the pair of entries you want to swap, and add everything back up.

I doubt this is what you're after.

Comment: You're correct in saying there is no single matrix which can generate an arbitrary permutation. This is because left and right multiplication can only permute the rows and columns respectively. I find this easiest to see when considering permutations on rectangular matrices where you cannot even ensure the left and right matrices are the same size.

Comment: Nope, not at all. Computationally inefficient, strongly so. @Cyclo, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is no such $B$ (EDIT: assuming you want a fixed $B$ that works for every $A$).  The $j$'th row of $AB$ is (the $j$'th row of $A$) $B$.  It doesn't depend on any other row.  You can do any linear transformation of that row (but you will be doing the same linear transformation to each of the other rows).

Comment: I figured as much, but was curious to see if there is any method that resembles such a B. Approximate or otherwise.

Comment: I want a $B$ for a given pair of positions in the matrix $A$.