# Convert a row vector to column vector through a matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have $X$ a $1\times n$ row vector, and I need to convert it into a column vector through explicit matrix multiplications. That is equivalent to ask for the transpose of $X$, so in other words:

Is it possible to find a $A$ and $B$ so that

$AXB=X^{T}$

(Probably 2 matrices needed given the sizes). 
Do you have any idea how I can build $A$ and $B$? It should depend on $n$ of course, but I'd like to find a general expression.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no $M$ that will do this for all row-vectors $X$

Comment: Regarding your edit: there is no pair $A,B$ that will do this for all row-vectors $X$

Comment: I edited the mistake.

Comment: As can be seen from the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2775198/81360), many permutations of the elements of $X$ (including $X \mapsto X^T$) cannot be implemented by a map of the form $X \mapsto AXB$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $X$ is $1 \times n$ and $AXB$ has size $n \times 1$, then $A$ must have size $n \times 1$ and $B$ must have size $n \times 1$.  Thus, we have
$$
AXB = A(XB)
$$
where we note that $XB$ is $1 \times 1$, i.e. a scalar.  Thus, we can only have $AXB = X^T$ if $X^T$ is a scalar multiple of $A$.  Thus, there is no $A$ (and no combination of $A$ and $B$) that will satisfy $AXB = X^T$ for all $X$.

Comment: That's a nice answer thanks! Do you know of any other way (other than this AXB form) to construct the transpose using a set of explicit matrices?

Comment: I'm not sure what "constructing the transpose using a set of explicit matrices" entails exactly.  Could you say a bit about what it is that you're trying to do with this formula?