# Prove a matrix $B$ is the result of matrix $A$ undergoing $n$ row and column exchanges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a square matrix $A$ which is $m\times m$ large, for example:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and a shuffled version of it, for example:
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
a & e & b\\
d & c & i\\
h & g & f
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is it possible to prove that $B$ is a product of $A$ undergoing an unknown number of row and column exchanges? (for example, swap row 1 with row 2, then, swap column 2 with column 3, ...)

As far as I know, I can disprove it if they have different values for the absolute value of their determinant, but say they have the same determinant or one has the negative determinant of the other?

How about if the matrix is not square?

Comment: [Does this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2775198/81360) answer your question?

Comment: Following the line of reasoning in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2775562/81360): no matter how you switch rows and columns, $b$ and $e$ have to end up in the same column.  This rules out your example

Comment: @Omnomnomnom maybe? The example with the 2x2 matrix makes perfect sense - it is obvious that it is not a valid permutation under my conditions. However the comment after stating their rank must be equal to be a valid permutation under the conditions, is that exclusive? i.e. Is there no possibility of a permutation existing with the same rank that *wasn't* a product of row/column exchanges?

Comment: No: the fact that the shuffled matrix has the same rank is not enough to deduce that we could get to it with row and column switches.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom right the diagonal reasoning makes sense to me I think, that no element on the diagonal $(a, e, i)$ can exist on the same row/column in the product