# Characteristic polynomials of two matrices containing the same elements

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial, permutation-matrices

I asked this question in a slightly different form and didn't receive any comments. Two real, symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ contain the same elements (in different orders). They also have the same characteristic polynomial,

$\mathrm{det} \left[ A - \lambda I \right] = \mathrm{det} \left[ B - \lambda I \right]$.

Does this imply that the matrices are related by a signed permutation,

$A$ = $PBP^{T}$,

where $P$ is the signed permutation?

I am not a mathematician, so I have no idea if this question is trivial to people in the know. Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit:

In a comment, Ben Grossmann pointed out this related question,

[Can you completely permute the elements of a matrix by applying permutation matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775198/can-you-completely-permute-the-elements-of-a-matrix-by-applying-permutation-matr)

One of the answers there says the following,

Given two elements $_1$ and $_2$, the properties "$_1$ and $_2$ are on different rows" and "$_1$ and $_2$ are on different columns" are preserved by any permutation.

Rephrasing my original question, if matrix $A$ satisfies the property above and matrix $B$ does not, do they necessarily have different characteristic polynomials?

Comment: It [is not necessarily true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2775198/81360) that if $A$ and $B$ have the same elements, then there exist signed permutation $P,Q$ such that $A = PBQ^T$. I'm not sure that the characteristic polynomial being the same is enough to ensure that this condition holds with $P = Q$

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I had come across the link you gave while researching this question. Your answer and the others there point out that the rank of a matrix is not necessarily preserved by an arbitrary permutation of its elements, whereas a permutation of its rows and columns does preserve its rank. Here I have assumed A and B have the same rank (by assuming they have the same characteristic polynomial), so the ideas presented in the link don't seem so helpful for my question.

Comment: I don't know the answer when $A$ and $B$ are PSD. If $A$ and $B$ are only symmetric, the answer is "no": consider e.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0\\ &&0&-1\\ &&-1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1\\ &&1\\ &&&-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the importance of the PSD requirement, but thanks to your example I now see that it is essential. I didn't mention it in the question, but the matrices I have in mind are Gramians formed from points on the unit sphere (so two or three positive eigenvalues in general and ones on the diagonal).